# How find min/max of $(a+b+c)^3abc$ with condition on $a,b,c$

Tags: inequality

> Let $a,b,c$ be positive numbers, such that 
>   $$ab+bc+ac=1$$
>   find the minimum and maximum of $$f(a,b,c)=(a+b+c)^3\cdot abc$$

My try:
$$(a+b+c)^3abc\ge 3(ab+bc+ac)(a+b+c)abc=3abc(a+b+c)$$

or other idea
let $$p=a+b+c, q=ab+bc+ac=1, r=abc$$

then $$f(a,b,c)=p^3r$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The range is all positive numbers.

To convince yourself that we can reach close to 0, take $a \rightarrow 0$ and $ b=c $. Then we clearly have $ b = c \leq 1 $ and so $(a+b+c)^3 \times a bc \leq 3^3 \times a  \rightarrow 0$.

To convince yourself that we can reach infinity, take $a = b \rightarrow 0$. Then $ c \approx \frac{1}{2a} > \frac{1}{3a} $ and so $ (a+b+c)^3 \times abc \geq c^4 \times ab \geq \frac{1}{9a^2} \rightarrow \infty. $

Comment: BUt,I have question: $a,b,c<1$,then  $(a+b+c)^3\cdot abc<(1+1+1)^3\cdot1\cdot 1\cdot 1=8?$

Comment: @chinamath What is your point? $ab+bc+ca = 1$ does not imply that $a, b, c < 1$.

Comment: e,Thank you,I kown,+1